# How to efficiently validate all args in Javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, types, typeof

I work with Javascript (Typescript), more specifically with React. So this question is written in Javascript but it's more like a general question.

I'm trying to **refactor** some code and extract **static methods**. Once I extract the method, I find myself checking if all arguments received are valid. This becomes hard to read and, sometimes, the real purpose of the function has only a few lines.

Here's an example of how I would end up writing a method / function

```
const isGreaterThan = (value1, value2) => {
  if(typeof value1 !== 'number'){
    console.error("Invalid argument. value1 must be a number");
    return 0;
  }
  if(typeof value2 !== 'number'){
    console.error("Invalid argument. value2 must be a number");
    return 0;
  }
  return value1 > value2
}
```

Now imagine if this method receives an `Array`

```
const isGreaterThanAll = (values, value1) => {
  if(!values instanceof Array){
    console.error("Invalid argument. values must be an Array");
    return 0;
  }
  if(!values.every(value => typeof value === 'number')){
    console.error("Invalid argument. elements of values must be numbers");
    return 0;
  }
  if(typeof value1 !== 'number'){
    console.error("Invalid argument. value2 should be type of number");
    return 0;
  }
  return values.every(value => value1 > value);
}
```

Now imagine passing an `Object` or an `Array` of `Object`s. Depending on the complexity of the arguments, this becomes harder to follow.

Some of my questions are:

- Which is the best practice to refactor code in this scenario?
- How can I refactor this kind of code to be more readable?
- Should I build a method to check arguments?

Comment: where are you using these functions? just in your own codebase or are they exposed externally? if it's your codebase and you said you're using typescript, just assign a type to the arguments, like `const isGreaterThan = (value1: number, value2: number)`

Comment: @szaman sometimes I use them only internally and I can trust Typescript but in some cases I need to check errors also in runtime, for example when I use them with an API response. In this cases compile time doesn't work for me because if I assume a type and it changes, it will silently fail in production :'(

Comment: @Lukas this looks like TDD but in reverse. For such cases you are writing tests first and in test you are checking whenever type is correct and making assertion for certain final result. And before building and pushing to production you are running test suites and checking if your function give excepted results. I think better way is to add type hints as szaman said and add tests for such functions were you can put your filters. Another advice would be to create some kind of json schema by which you can validate your parameters.

Comment: @Lucas Use typescript and trust your declared types. Remove type validation from your business logic and helper functions. If you don't trust an API response, check *that* for types where you receive it; when valid pass it to your functions. Don't do the validation in functions like `isGreaterThan` or `isGreaterThanAll`, it has no place there.

Comment: @SergeyLigus Maybe I'm applying TDD in a wrong way, because I found myself writing this "if checks" due to failing tests. For example, a test I would write for this method will be something like `test("...", () => { expect(isGreaterThan(5, undefined)).toBe(0) }` and mock the console.error fn to check if it has been called. To cover `undefined` argument, I have to check `typeof` argument.

Comment: @Lucas if you are using JEST then first look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319741/testing-function-parameter-data-types-in-jest).  And instead of test by test, i would rather use [describe with map](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#describeeachtablename-fn-timeout) in combination with previous thread answer.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it is to create a recursive function like this.

```js
const isNumberOrArrayOfNumbers = (x) => {
  if (typeof x === 'number') {
    return true;
  }
  if ( Array.isArray(x) ) {
    return x.every(n => isNumberOrArrayOfNumbers(n));
  }
  return false;
};

const isGreaterThanAll = (values, value1) => {

  let valid = [values, value1].every(a => isNumberOrArrayOfNumbers(a));
  
  if (!valid) {
    console.error('Invalid');
    return Number.NaN;
  }


  return values.every(value => value1 > value);
};

console.log( isGreaterThanAll([1,2,3,5,6,7],12) );
console.log( isGreaterThanAll([1,2,3,5,6,7],4) );
console.log( isGreaterThanAll([1,2,3,"r",5,6,7],12) );
```

If you're willing to change the signature of the function you could also refactor by making it variadic and using [rest operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

That might look something like this:

```
const isGreaterThanAll = (n, ...m) => {
    let valid = [n, ...m].every(x => typeof x === 'number');
    ...
};
```